# Share Outlook 'Quick Steps' to other users

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I want to create a template for a 'Send Email' quick step in Outlook 2010 and be able to share it to other people, whether via file or policy or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done... In some tricky way. Since Quick Steps are stored in the storage (PST/mailbox), you cannot deploy it using Group Policy or other "standard" way.

However, if you will create a shared mailbox (assuming you're using Exchange Server) and create required Quick Steps there... then all users with access to this particular mailbox will also have access to all Quick Steps stored in it.

I don't think there are other ways to share Quick Steps.

Comment: Has there been an update to this in the last 8 years?

Comment: @wizlog Nope, sorry )